# What does the BLE ScanRecord's getServiceData contain?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

I have an application which connects to Bluetooth Low Energy devices. The service UUID gives a good indication, but it is not enough: I'd need to see which exact characteristics the device offers within a specific service. I see that there's a so called "service data" within the ScanRecord which is a series of bytes:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanRecord#getServiceData()

However I cannot find any detail about that anywhere: what is the information in that service data? In nRF connect it seems that it's a byte (or a few bytes), so maybe it's some kind of a bit flag. I'm hoping that service data might save me from discovering the device because that would require connecting to it, which I want to really avoid.

To have a more concrete example: I support FTMS Fitness Machines (0x1826), but only Indoor Bike (0x2ad2 characteristic), Treadmill (0x2acd), or Rower (0x2ad1), but not cross trainer, step machine, or stair climber.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advertisement does not contain data about what characteristics the device has.

There are advertisement types for service uuids, but not for characteristics specified by the standard.

Usually if you know what services are supported, you should be able to assume the characteristics too since each service's specification document should contain that info.

The "service data" just contains arbitrary bytes. What these bytes contain is defined by the service's specification.

Comment: So the content of the bytes are not manufacturer proprietary, but defined by the GATT service specification?

Comment: Content of bytes in service data for custom uuids are custom. Content of bytes in service data for service uuids defined by bluetooth sig are defined by their specification. The gatt specification itself does not specify content of service data, it's the specification of each service that does so.

Comment: So basically this was an RTFM on my end. Coincidentally the FTMS service standard does provide hint about the characteristics, because I'm sure the standard committee was aware of the situation I'm in. Kudos to them. I'll need to add my own answer to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

@Emil's answer is valid for a general case. As for my specific example I'd need to add an answer, because it does provide information about the characteristic (fortunately). FTMS service can represent a wide variety of exercise equipment: indoor bike, treadmill, rower, cross trainer, step machine, stair machine. These all implement a different characteristic within the service to supply the equipment specific data. And in my case I possibly want to know even during the scan phase which type is the equipment without having to pair with the device.

So basically this is a case of RTFM (Read The Fine Manual), and after studying the FTMS standard documentation I can happily say that advertisement data in case of FTMS (0x1826) has a so called "Fitness Machine Type" field, which is a 2 byte long bit flag. In the 78 page long specification PDF this is on page 15-16. The bits of that flag:

- Bit 0: Treadmill Supported
- Bit 1: Cross Trainer Supported
- Bit 2: Step Climber Supported
- Bit 3: Stair Climber Supported
- Bit 4: Rower Supported
- Bit 5: Indoor Bike Supported
- Bit 6-15: Future use

The standard committee must have realized this use-case, kudos to them. I'll take advantage of this in my software soon.